# getting an error in swift for some UI ode when creating a frame and button

Tags: swift, swiftui

When I create a button for the frame of my Vstack I gat an error code called : Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'Alignment' that does not accept a closure I do not know what this means or shat is causing it but if you know please help

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10)
        {
        Text("Welcome TimberWolves")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .foregroundColor(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.blue/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            Text("This Is The New School App!")
                .foregroundColor(Color.green)
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 100)
        {
        Button(action: {}){
                Text("Button")
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to put 2 texts and a button in a `VStack`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is becouse you try to add button outside of VStack. Try to add button inside Vstack

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
            Text("Welcome TimberWolves")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
            Text("This Is The New School App!")
                .foregroundColor(.green)
            Button(action: {}) {
                Text("Button")
            }
        }
    .frame(width: 300, height: 100)
    }
}
```